# Implement 2 payment options at chechkout (WP + WooCommerce website)

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, braintree

I`ve a WP site with WooCommerce plugin.

I need to implement two payment options at the checkout:
1) pay in full; 2) make an upfront payment of 50%
the customer should be able to choose

here`s an example - http://prntscr.com/b1a97c

maybe, there`s a good plugin for it?

P.S. I know you may find this question a trivial one. However I`m just making my first steps in coding and I really need your help to puzzle this issue out.

Comment: Search in google: "https://www.google.fr/search?q=wordpress+deposit+payment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need to use two payment options, You can create configurable product with one attribute "Payment Option", their should have two option.

1. Full Payment ( With full price)
2. Half or 50% payment ( With 50% product price )

So, user can select any option and on this options price will be changes as you assign it.

Answer (score 0):

The Woothemes Deposits plugin (https://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-deposits/) will allow the user to select to pay in full or to pay a 50% deposit up front and the rest at a time designated by you. You can also set up payment plans with multiple subsequent payments and customize the percentages.

I recently used it on a project and found it to be fairly straightforward and adaptable.